# wpf Drag and Drop at exact mouse location

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a ListBox and a Canvas. I want to Drag a ListBoxItem onto a Canvas exactly where the mouse is placed.This is my xaml. Problem is the items are placed one on top of other irrespective of the mouse position. How can I place the dragged items at the exact location based on the mouse pointer on the canvas. Please help.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="lstLabels">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>

                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>B</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>C</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>D</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>E</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>F</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>G</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>H</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <Canvas AllowDrop="True" Background="Azure"
                DragEnter="cvsSurface_DragEnter" Drop="cvsSurface_Drop" 
                Name="cvsSurface" >
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
```

This is my complete cs code

```
 private ListBoxItem draggedItem;
 private Point startDragPoint;
private void cvsSurface_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }
        private void cvsSurface_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Label newLabel = new Label();
            newLabel.Content = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);

            cvsSurface.Children.Add(newLabel);
            Canvas.SetLeft(newLabel, 100);
            Canvas.SetTop(newLabel, 200);

            draggedItem = null;
            lstLabels.SelectedItem = null;
        }
        private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            draggedItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
            startDragPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
        }
        private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point position = e.GetPosition(null);
            if (draggedItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.Content, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your 'dropped' label layout position is hardcoded as {100, 200}, why would you expect them not to appear one over the other? Use the `DragEventArgs`' `GetPosition()` method to get the relative mouse point within the `Cavas`.

Comment: Sorry my Bad. As you said I did

  var canvas = sender as Canvas;
            var positionX = e.GetPosition(canvas).X;
            var positionY = e.GetPosition(canvas).Y;

and passed as parameters instead of 100 and 200 and it works fine. I am leaving the post as it is if it is helpful to someone.

Comment: One question Andrew. Lets say now the list box item is an ellipse or a rectangle. Now in the cvsSurface_Drop event I say something like 
StackPanel p=new StackPanel();
p.Children.Add( e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
Now what do I say instead of Text to add a shape?

Comment: The [DragEventArgs.Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.idataobject(v=vs.110).aspx) object has a number of methods for querying which formats are available. But if you are only using Rectangles and Ellipses, you could use something like e.Data.GetData(typeof(Shape)). Even still, I think you'll need some additional logic to recreate the shapes since you can't just add a UIElement into the visual tree twice.

Comment: Thanks Andrew I think I need to retrieve the shape from visual tree. When I am trying something like  UIElement sp = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Shape)) as UIElement;  
The sp is always null. So I need to get the shape based on id from the visualtree right?

Comment: You shouldn't have to use the VisualTree. Put a breakpoint there and use the e.Data.GetDataPresent methods to see which dataTypes are available. What I was implying is that you will not be able to place the retrieved Shape directly onto the Cavas, you'll need to create a new shape with the same properties.

Comment: I tried something like  var type = e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Shape));
When I drag and drop an ellipse put a breakpoint it says false.Can you please post an example Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my OnDrop handler to assign position to label

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CanvasDragDrop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private ListBoxItem draggedItem;

        private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            draggedItem = sender as ListBoxItem;

            if (draggedItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.Content, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }

        }


        private void CvsSurface_OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            }

        }

        private void CvsSurface_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Object droppedData = e.Data; //This part is not important

        /*Translate Drop Point in reference to Stack Panel*/
            Point dropPoint = e.GetPosition(this.cvsSurface);

            Console.WriteLine(dropPoint); ;
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Content = draggedItem.Content;
            cvsSurface.Children.Add(lbl);

            Canvas.SetLeft(lbl, dropPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(lbl, dropPoint.Y);

        }



    }
}
```

Also you need fewer events

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasDragDrop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="lstLabels">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>


                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>B</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>C</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>D</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>E</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>F</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>G</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>H</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <Canvas AllowDrop="True" Background="Azure"
                DragEnter="CvsSurface_OnDragEnter" Drop="CvsSurface_OnDrop" 
                Name="cvsSurface" >
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks now I can add the droppeddata to stackpanel as
Object droppedData = e.Data as Shape;